# How to install upload progress in Cpanel?

Tags: php, file-upload, cpanel

Hi, I am trying to install upload progress in Cpanel using the following steps:

1. Open  Software >> Module Installers and search upload progress
2. Then install
3. Then I get some message(`/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/uploadprogress.so`)

After the install, I get the response:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/uploadprogress.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/uploadprogress-1.0.3.1
Extension uploadprogress enabled in php.ini
The uploadprogress.so object is not in /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/uploadprogress.so
```

1. Then I copy
2. Then I go to  `Main >> Service Configuration >> PHP Configuration Editor`
3. And I find extension_dir
4. Then paste this message
5. Then I restart apache

Is this the right way to install upload progress?

I still can't get the `uploadprogress_get_info()` information.

Answer (score 0):

First try to update WHM and reinstall the extension.

There´s a common inconsistence in whm/cpanel, and that can be your case.

Look at http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/uploadprogress-so-object-not-usr-local-lib-php-extensions-no-deb-249481.html

You´ll need to look at the logs to be sure.

For alternate methods look at:

http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/installing-acp-uploadprogress-tutorial-107265.html

I recommend pecl to install extensions via shell. More control, best results, discarding interface bugs.

Comment: yes i see the links ..so i edit my question please check response once